# Why it does not return after execlp? Is it normal?

Tags: c, linux

So I'm new to C and this is one problem I have and cannot understand. First, execlp() executes a program just by name(by searching for it) with parameters. Here I want to execute "who" with "-u" as parameter, but it does not return anything from execlp. Why? Is this normal?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    main()
    {
        int j = 0;
        if(fork() == 0)
        {
            j++;
            if(execlp("who", "who", "-u", (char*)0) == -1)
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nStoinostta na j = %d", j);
                return;
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            --j;
            printf("\nStoinostta na j=%d", j);
        }
        printf("\nStoinostta na j ravno na %d", ++j);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

On success, `execlp` *replaces* the current process with the command that you specify. It will only return if it fails. The manpage should make this clear.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by @Charles Bailey, `execlp()` replaces the current process.  So it never returns after running a program.

If you want to just run something, a simple way is with `system()`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

If you want to run something and control input and output, possibly collecting the output from the command, a good way is `popen()`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Comment: Very well then, I'll edit the text to say it never returns after running a program.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want the `system` function. It will run another program and then return.

Another option would be to `exec` after calling `fork`.

```
fork() || execlp(...);
```